# Question on yield criteria

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Consider a cubic body subjected to a hydrostatic pressure state where $$\sigma_I=\sigma_{II}=\sigma_{III}=X$$ and the definitions of the Rankine, Tresca and Mises yield criteria, given e. g. under: https://mae.ufl.edu/haftka/adv-elast/lectures/Sections4-3-4.pdf . It seems to me that under these conditions, the criteria (and their assignment to brittle or ductile materials) don't always make proper sense.

First, let's assume that $X$ is a compressive stress ($X<0$). In that case according to Rankine, the equivalent stress is $\sigma_{eq}=|X|$. If we assume the cause of Rankine yielding to be the separation of atomic bonds, that doesn't seem to make sense since it cannot occur under compression. Tresca and Mises result in an equivalent stress of $\sigma_{eq}=0$, which seems more realistic since by my understanding, a continuum cannot fail under hydrostatic pressure. So I'd conclude that Rankine doesn't work here and Tresca/Mises is correct for all materials.

Now let $X$ be a tensile stress ($X>0$), which seems to turn things upside down: Rankine ($\sigma_{eq}=|X|$) makes sense now, but Tresca and Mises ($\sigma_{eq}=0$) seem to fail since I'd guess that if $X$ becomes great enough, it would ultimately lead to a separation of atomic bonds and thus Rankine failure.

Are my conclusions correct? And if so, why don't we always check every criterion in practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common yield criteria used in practice are approximate theories which have broad applicability to common materials and structures; however, they are *not* perfect descriptions. There is no yield criterion which can be universally applied to all materials.

In the notes you link to, the maximum principle stress theory is indicated to be applied "mostly in tension" where it makes more sense.

The Tresca and von Mises yield criteria make the following underlying assumptions. Tresca assumes that yielding occurs when the shear stress reaches a critical value; whereas, the von Mises yield criterion assumes yielding occurs when the distortional energy (i.e. the energy associated with shape change) reaches a maximum value. These assumptions lead to the conclusion that yielding is independent of the hydrostatic stress. This result was found experimentally to be valid for many metals, but even then, there is likely a maximum pressure above which this is not true. Nevertheless, there are pressure dependent forms of both the Tresca and von Mises yield criteria.

See the Mohr-Coulomb and Drucker-Prager yield criteria:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_surface

When a new material is being studied for applications where yielding is important, it is most rigorous to test which yield criteria is applicable to the new material.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So the commonly used criteria are indeed not 100 % complete and there are theoretical cases where they fail (like the von Mises or Tresca criterion under hydrostatic tension), but "in practice" they are sufficiently accurate.